# Why should not use too much GLOBAL variables in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

GLOBAL variables can be reached by all files in project , it is generally advantege for developer because you define just one time and you do not need to export from other files but i heard that some problems can occur if i use too much GLOBAL variables in nodeJS.
     Moreover , i want to use my mongoose models as global variables because , i'am using them most of times almost every project files , is it true way ?

Comment: From my point of view sticking with import/export modules is a better approach, since it force you to keep architecture in mind. Too much globals leads easily to a mistakes and lack of tests.

Comment: so , Are there any problem about memory usage ?

Comment: I don't think so. A good use of GLOBAL is for constants (environment data) eventually for libraries you will use everywhere in your app (e.g.: lodash). If you think you need to put something else in the GLOBAL namespace, it would be a clue about a lack of seperation of concerns. Plus it could lead to conflict between several components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global variables but it's safer is you sore all your application's variables under a global namespace instead of creating a lot of single variable that could be already used by other libraries in your project.
A safer way to define a global namenspace containing variables is:

```
var MY_APP_NAMESPACE = {
  app_name: 'My App',
  app_version: '0.0.1'
};
```

Then, you can get your global variables using the following syntax:

```
function myFunction() {
  var version = MY_APP_NAMESPACE.app_version;
}
```

Comment: Make sense :D , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is an age old question. You don't use the global namespace BECAUSE of the danger of conflicts - someone else (if you are working on a GIT project) might declare the same global with the same name and problems then occur.

also, globals make it difficult to debug. If the variable contains the wrong value, for example, then where in the codebase set that value? Not always obvious for large projects.

Comment: Yes, definitely, you're right!